What is the meaning of "@" symbol before awk regex
This it taken from the "awk-exercises".

For the input file patterns.txt, filter lines containing three or more
occurrences of "ar" and replace the last but second "ar" with "X"
par car tar far Cart
part cart mart
Expected output
par car tX far Cart
pXt cart mart

awk 'BEGIN{r = @/(.*)ar((.*ar){2})/} $0~r{print gensub(r, "\\1X\\2", 1)}' patterns.txt

There is one think I don't understand, what is the meaning of "@" in BEGIN block?

It looks like a way to save a regexp in a variable.

It's worth mentioning that gensub is a gawk (the GNU Project's implementation of the AWK programming language) extension not found in POSIX awk.

A little bit of background re: standard regex constants.
Without the @ prefix:
##### this:

r = /(.*)ar((.*ar){2})/

##### is comparable to this:

r = ($0 ~ /(.*)ar((.*ar){2})/)      # assign 'r' the value of the comparison, ie, r = 0 (false) or 1 (true)

NOTE: if r = /(.*)ar((.*ar){2})/ is performed in the BEGIN block (where $0 is undefined) you'll always end up with r = 0 (false)
The obvious objective of this line of code is to assign a regex pattern to the variable r for use later in the script.
In GNU awk there are a couple approaches for assigning a regex pattern to a variable:

dynamic
regexps:
r = "(.*)ar((.*ar){2})"
strongly typed regex
constant:
r = @/(.*)ar((.*ar){2})/

So, to answer OP's question, r = @/.../ is one approach (strongly typed regex constant) available in GNU awk for assigning a regexp to a variable.
